Motivation behind this exercise problem on complete sufficient statistic
This is from Hogg and McKean's "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics" Chapter 7 (Sufficiency), section 7.4 (Completeness and Uniqueness).
Exercise 7.4.10.
Let $Y_1 < Y_2 < \cdots < Y_n$ be the order statistics of a random sample of size $n$ from a distribution with pdf $f (x; \theta) = 1/\theta,$ $0 < x < \theta$, zero elsewhere. By Example $7.4.2$, the statistic $Y_n$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and it has pdf
$$g(y_n;\theta)= \frac{ny_n^{n-1}}{\theta^n} , 0<y_n <\theta,$$
and zero elsewhere.
(a) Find the distribution function $H_n(z; \theta)$ of $Z = n(\theta − Y_n)$.
(b) Find the $\lim_{n \to \infty} H_n(z; \theta)$ and thus the limiting distribution of Z.
My Question:
Solution to this problem is very simple and I am not asking anything about solving this problem. In fact, he had given this problem before in an earlier exercise in a previous chapter and I had already solved it at that stage. My question is "what does this have anything to do with completeness and uniqueness?"
Further details about my question:
At this point in the text, the fact that the $n^{th}$ order statistic of a random sample from a uniform distribution $U(0,\theta)$ can be used as an estimator for $\theta$, has been beaten down to death. As he also mentions, it was established (in example $7.4.2$) that it is a complete sufficient statistic, and that $n/(n+1)Y_n$ is the so called MVUE of $\theta$. It just felt very odd that he gives a question (whose parts (a) and (b) were asked before) whose solution seemingly has nothing to do with completeness.
I'd appreciate it if you can see any connection between the solution to this exercise and completeness i.e. if you can see the motivation behind asking this question in the section on completeness, kindly illuminate me about it.

Because this exercise is about a limiting distribution, what answer do you obtain for that?

$Z \sim \Gamma(1,\theta)$ ie exponential distribution. There is no mention about asymptotic distribution though, nor about its relationship to completeness till now (ie till section 7.4 in the completeness chapter).

"...thus the limiting distribution of..." refers to the asymptotic distribution.  The entire point of this exercise is for you to learn about this and have an example available for future study.

Thanks. Will look forward to learning about it in the later sections.
